# applying local dynamic range dependent on lookup values in Excel

Tags: excel, date, vlookup

Hello and thanks for reading this,

**what kind of data**
Imagine a Ice Cream Delivery Service. We have daily deliveries each delivery is uniquely defined and we have a fleet of delivery trucks and each truck has to be checked before departing to its destination. Now we have a record of all the deliveries and the according time spent for truck checking.

So basically the outcome we want is this:

[image: For Each period we want to highlight the checked trucks]

**We want to define time periods**
..in which a truck only has to be checked once. If the period was 4 days, the truck would be delivering without checking once it has been check for the first time in this time period. Each delivery has to automatically fall into it's period based on the delivery date (accomplished). After every delivery with a new  (in this period not yet checked) truck, the truck is taken into a group of trucks that will not have to be checked again. New deliveries will then be compared to that group to decide if it has to be checked or not.

**The tricky part is automatically applying the formula to the cells based on dates/periods like shown below:**

[image: new periods will have new truck number reference]

[image: The last column's values are where the Countif Area in column D should begin]
Can anyone help?

kind regards

Comment: I think you'll need COUNTIFS and additional criteria for the period start column and possibly the period end column too.

Comment: In what way your current formula is not working for you? please specify the expected out put based on your sample data and explain where went wrong with your current formula.

Comment: So the problem is more the changing area the formula has to be applied as the period duration can change, everything else has to change with it. Maybe the screenshot i just added can help you understand my dilemma. I used '=1 + MATCH(C14, $C$2$:$C$14,0)' to determine the row in which the area shouls start for each specific cell in column D (and it should end at that specific cell).