# have a area reference based on formula in formula

Tags: excel, reference, range, concatenation, countif

I so this problem has been bothering me for a while.

[image]

I want to have the *Checked or Not* -Column adapt if the period start and period end adapt (which are externally generated values in the original). To do this the start of the range in the formula of column D needs to adapt e.g. `=IF( COUNTIF(E$9:E9,E9)>1,"checked", "first check")` should be something like

```
=IF( COUNTIF(    CONCATENATE("E",1 + MATCH(C9, $C$2:$C$14,0))    :E9,E9)>1,"checked", "first check")
```

the Value in the CONCATENATE-part would spit out the exact row in which we have a new period start or end and then include this in the area function that compares the trucks

Comment: Why not just use `COUNTIFS` and include the period column(s) as criteria?

Comment: @Rory as I [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58715114/applying-local-dynamic-range-dependent-on-lookup-values-in-excel#comment103723748_58715114) yesterday :)

Comment: okay, could you maybe give me a minimal working example?

Comment: The important thing is I really want to have the formula look up the start of the range itself or take it from Column F!

This is really important to me